# HTTP Get in VB.Net how do I pass in the code from the body?

Tags: vb.net, http, get, webclient

There are a lot of examples of how to add parameters into WebClient but how do you pass in the code you have in the body (see my response below with image of what it looks like in Postman)? Below is my code:

```
        Using client As New WebClient()
            client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = AuthToken
            client.QueryString.Add("parameter1", "Hello world") 'Pass in parameter, but not sure how to pass in code from Body
            Dim json As String = client.DownloadString("https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Products")
            
            Dim ds1 As DataTable = GetDataTableFromJsonString(json)  
            Dim BindingSource1 = New BindingSource
            BindingSource1.DataSource = ds1
            DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        End Using
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

I tried client.QueryString.Add() to see if I can just put that string in there but it didn't work.

Comment: You may want to call `client.QueryString.Add()` **before** `client.DownloadString()` -- I don't know what *the code you have in the body* means

Comment: I have been using Postman to test, its the code highlighted in yellow, this works in postman, I just dont know how to add this code in VB (see picture): ![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/RpcThmP).

Comment: That's a JSON object, passed in the body of a POST request. I suggest you move to HttpClient (WebClient has been deprecated anyway)

Comment: OK, thank you.... I think I figured it out. I believe I was suppose to use client.UploadString(Get_COQL_Query, COQL_Body) (UploadString since its a POST and pass the body code as DATA) instead of using DownloadString. Anyhow thank you for your help.

Comment: Solved, Yeah, UploadString() worked....